# uniform convergence of a function series and related series sum

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Let $f_n:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $n \geq 1$ be defined as:

$f_n(x) = \cases{ x^n(\log x)^2 & \text{if } x\neq0\cr 0 & \text{if } x=0 }$

prove that $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}f_n(x)$ converges uniformly in $[0,1]$, and that

$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x (\log x)^2}{1-x}=2\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^3}$$

My attempt:

Using l'Hopital I find that $\lim_{x\to 0} x\log x=0$, and obviously $\lim_{x\to 1} x\log x=0$.

Since $f_n$ is continuous for all $n$ and [0,1] is compact $f_n$ is bounded $0 \leq f_n \leq k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{R}$.

And because $f_n < f_m$ in $(0,1)$ and for $n>m$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n=0$, $f_n$ converges uniformly in $[0,1]$.

Now $f_n(x)=g_n(x)^2=(x^{\frac{n}{2}}\log x)^2$, since we know that $g_n$ converges uniformly to $0$, if I prove that $\sum g_n$ is bounded then $\sum f_n$ converges uniformly by Dirichlet.

So how can I prove that $\sum g_n$ is bounded and how can I prove:

$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x (\log x)^2}{1-x}=2\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^3}$$

Comment: The integral depends on $n$ but the RHS doesn't. Are you sure is it right?

Comment: I suspect you need to take the limit of the integral on the left.

Comment: edited the n out of the integral

Answer (score 2):

We can see by summing a geometric series that $\sum f_n$ is point-wise convergent to the function $f$ defined by

$$f(x)=\frac{\ln^2 x}{1-x},\; \forall x\in(0,1)\quad ; \quad f(0)=f(1)=0$$

Moreover we have

$$f'_n(x)=x^{n-1}\log x(n\ln x+2)=0\iff x=e^{-2/n}, x=0,x=1$$
so we see that

$$||f_n||_\infty=f_n(e^{-2/n})=\frac{4e^{-2}}{n^2}$$
hence by the Weierstrass M-test the given series is uniformly convergent on $[0,1]$.

Comment: To get the value of the integral expand the function $\frac{x}{1-x}$ into a Taylor series about $x=0$ and integrate the resulting expression term-by-term.